Does this infinite sum converge or diverge?
This has more of a physics background but I thought to post this here due to the complexity of it. I've been looking at pendulums, particularly those that exceed the small angle approximation and a component of the formula for period time is this infinite sum:
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left( \frac{(2n-1)!!}{(2n)!!} \right)^2(1-\delta)
$$
Where $\delta$ is small. I'm wondering if this sum converges or diverges.

Why $(1-\delta)$ is under sum?

Originally there's a half angle of sine squared that if equal to one causes the system to be at "equilibrium". The $(1-\delta)$ is meant to represent really close to one, but not so it causes this issue.

Since this factor does not depend on the summation index, it does not affect convergence - your main question.

I suspect there is a typo in your expression. If it is $$I = 1 + \sum_{n=\color{red}{1}}^\infty \left(\frac{(2n-1)!!}{2n!!}\right)^2(1-\delta)^{\color{red}{n}},$$ then $I = {}_2F_1(\frac12,\frac12;1;1-\delta) = \frac{2}{\pi}K(\sqrt{1-\delta})$ where ${}_2F_1$ and $K$ are hypergeometric function and complete elliptic integral of first kind respectively.
$I(\delta)$ blows up like $\frac{1}{\pi}\log\frac1{\delta}$ as $\delta \to 0^{+}$.

Let's consider little more general case with power $p$, understanding, that double factorial notation is used respectively for all odd end even numbers production
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left( \frac{(2n-1)!!}{(2n)!!} \right)^p=\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^p+\left(\frac{1\cdot 3}{2 \cdot 4}\right)^p+\cdots$$
we have
$$\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}= \left(1+\frac{1}{2n+1}\right)^p=1+\frac{p}{2n+1}+\frac{p(p-1)}{2(2n+1)^2}+o\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$
from here with $p>2$ series converges and with $p\leqslant 2$ diverges.

Straightforward! I want to add the rates for completeness:
for $p = 2$ it diverges as $log(n)$, for $p\leq 2$ it diverges as $n^{1-\frac{p}{2}}$ and similarly for $p>2$ it converges as $n^{\frac{p}{2} - 1}$

Thanks. But there are down voters also and they are welcome to express their thoughts, if have any, especially as answer is correct and complete.

Answer to the updated question
It seems to me it diverges.
By using Stirling's asymptotic
$$n!\approx \sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n$$
one obtains
$$(2n-1)!!\approx \sqrt{4n-2}\left(\frac{2n-1}{e}\right)^{(2n-1)/2}$$
and
$$(2n)!!\approx \sqrt{2\pi n} \left(\frac{2n}{e}\right)^n.$$
The general term of the sum is then asymptotic to
$$\approx \left((2\pi)^{-1/2}\sqrt{\frac{2n-1}{n}}\cdot \sqrt{\frac{e}{2n-1}}\cdot \left(\frac{2n-1}{2n}\right)^n \right)^2$$
or simplifying
$$\approx \frac{1}{2\pi} \cdot \frac{e}{n}\cdot \left( 1-\frac{1}{2n}\right)^{2n}\stackrel{n\rightarrow \infty}{\approx} \frac{1}{2\pi n}.$$
So, assuming I have not made any mistake, the sum diverges asymptotically as $\ln(n)$.
There was a typo and a factorial on the denominator but I will leave this.
Assuming you are using the double "$!!$" to indicate the double factorial (meaning the product of the integers from $1$ to $k$ with the same parity of $k$) then the sum converges.
First of all, clearly it's behaviour does not depend on $\delta$ because we can simply factor out the term $(1-\delta)$.
What remains is
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left(\frac{(2n-1)!!}{(2n)!}\right)^2$$
which is strictly less than
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left(\frac{(2n-1)!}{(2n)!}\right)^2$$
and this is actually just
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{4n^2}=\frac{\pi ^2}{24}.$$
We bounded our sum with a convergent one so it converges.

I'm so sorry, the denominator is also a double factorial which I mistyped!
